# jBPM 4.4 and BPMN version

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

All,
what version of BPMN does jBPM  4.4 comply to?

Meaning is jBPM 4.4 is "BPMN 1.2" or "BPMN 2.0" compliant?

And how different is BPMN 1.2 from BPMN 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just got the details.. jBPM 4.4 supports, BPMN 1.2.